# Unite view can work as UIwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitextview

In `UIwebview` we can detect Phone, `URL` , mail address. Can it is possible to detect all items like `webview` in `UITextview` control.
 Please share you views.

Comment: Look at `dataDetectorTypes` property of `UITextView`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement like this:

In your view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *abc;
```

Links are not clickable by default in a `UITextView`  for that use this:

```
self.abc.text = content;
self.abc.editable = NO; 
self.abc.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

and make sure that `User Interaction Enabled` was checked at the bottom of the View section of IB's Attributes Inspector(if you are going to use xib).